# Adding to he format dropdown menu tinyMCE in Wordpress

Tags: tinymce, formatting

Does anyone know the steps needed to add a custom format to the blockformat (p,h1,h2,h3 etc.) dropdown in the tinyMCE editor in Wordpress?

I've found a lot of different ways to do that, which seem to either contradict each other or have absolutely no effect.

I've had very little interaction with Wordpress as a developer so I'm not even sure where what is located.
wordpress tinymce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function extend_tiny_mce_defaults( $config )
{
    // comma separated list of any block-level HTML tag
    $config['theme_advanced_blockformats'] = 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,code,address';
    return $init;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'extend_tiny_mce_defaults', 100 );
```

Comment: Where does that go, and does that method allow me to add a custom block format of my design?

Comment: Drop it in a plugin or your theme's `functions.php`. As for your 'custom' block format, if it's not just a standard HTML element (i.e. you want it to do a little more) you might be better off implementing a [custom Tiny MCE button](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons) instead.

Comment: I ended up installing Advanced TinyMCE Configuration
 and Advanced TinyMCE Configuration, was working great until I updated 3.3 and now style doesn't get rendered in the editor, but other wise works fine.